# What gems would be good to implement feature like SO's Badge system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am wondering if there is any gem out there that works similar to Stackoverflow's Badges system for Rails 3 application.

Comment: Hi, @user482594, As far as I'm aware there in nothing like that, but you can be the first one to start a gem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at this a while ago, and have this Stackoverflow question bookmarked to refer back to when I get around to implementing a similar system. It might help you too:

[How to implement an achievement system in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885277/how-to-implement-an-achievement-system-in-ror)