# Achievement model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Building off this question, [How to implement an achievement system in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885277/how-to-implement-an-achievement-system-in-ror) would I have a user_id column in my Achievement table?

Comment: really a down vote? Sorry, I thought this was a site for asking questions about programming. My bad.

Comment: I'd like to better understand the reasoning behind closing this question. I'm pretty sure 'would I have a user_id column in my Achievement table' is a "real" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the accepted answer way of doing this, then yes, you would have a user_id in your achievements table. You can tell this because in the Achievements model, it has:

```
belongs_to :user
```

If you were generating the achievements model through a rails generator, it would look like this:

```
rails g model Achievement user:references ........
```

Where ..... is the other fields in the achievement model.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I started over thinking this because I read on the linked question about a UNIQUE index on the 'Type' column. That made me wonder how multiple users could have the same achievements. Wouldn't the type be non-unique in that case?

Comment: They propose an index on the Type and User_ID column (the index across both, not two indexes). The combination of Type and User_ID being unique prevents multiple of the same achievement being recorded to one user.